# Can’t see grub menu on boot up from windows

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows-11

today is my first day installing and using Ubuntu. Took a while but finally able to install and use it as a dual boot in my windows 11 Lenovo Legion laptop. So when I shut it down from Ubuntu, and booting it up again I can see the Grub menu and choose which OS to boot, I tried changing back to windows and now I don’t get the same menu when booting up after previously shutting down *from windows. I pressed F12 to show the boot menu and saw Ubuntu is there, I pressed it but Windows os is still the one that’s booted up. I tried to set ‘time to display list of operating system’ from the windows advanced system setting but still can’t have the option. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That also means Windows fast startup/hibernation must be off. And bitlocker must be off. Windows updates may turn fast startup back on, also. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred thank you. I’ll try implementing it. Now I’m running into a new problem, that is, i set bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi in the windows administrator cmd. I believe it can’t find them and now my laptop is infinitely booting. Hope the solution you gave will help me

Comment: If you have UEFI Secure Boot on, the grubx64.efi will not work, not sure if then shimx64.efi which Ubuntu uses for Secure Boot works or not. Secure boot requires all files to be signed and not sure if same signing is now used. You can try with Secure boot off, if that is issue.

Comment: I see, now I can’t seem to fix my problem. I’ve read some guides online but nothing works for me. Because I set the bootmgr to grubx64.efi, that does not work, so it kinda is stuck to it and does reboot infinitely. The problem is I can’t enter windows safe mode after following some guides, is it because the state of my laptop is currently not Windows nor Ubuntu? So I’m not sure how I can set the bootmgr back.

Comment: You probably need to boot your Windows repair/recovery flash drive to fix Windows. Boot Ubuntu live installer and add Boot-Repair. Post link to summary report.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for your help. finally got both bootloader working again by re making them from terminal using live flash. Turns out the shimx64 and grubx64 gets deleted somehow, I used boot-repair to “reinstall them” and got the grub working